# banshee has its own id3 tags?

Tags: banshee, mp3, mp3-player, mp3-tag, sansa-clip

An mp3 player called "SanDisk Clip" will freeze if any song names have non-ascii characters (e.g. accented letters, like é á ó , etc.)

I have some mp3 files in banshee that I would like to add to the mp3 player, but some of them have non-ascii letters in their song name, artist name, etc.

So I copied themm to a new folder.  I used 3 different mp3 tag editing command lines tools to strip the id3 tags (v1 and v2) from the desired files, just to be safe.  I also wrote a script that changed the mp3 file names to remove non-ascii letters.

Now I load this directory of tag-less, ascii-safe mp3 files to Banshee.   Banshee still recognizes a bunch of them and their song names & artist etc. appear with the non-ascii accented letters.

How does Banshee do this?  How does Banshee put the "old" song name on a tag-less mp3?

Comment: Have you checked out the file in, say, ghex? And are you sure you stripped all the tags? ID3 can exist as both a header and a footer to the file. Removing the ID3 tags entirely wouldn't make things better. Lots of software determines Mp3 filetype by the presence of an ID3 tag.

Comment: Pro tip: Puddletag is a great tag editing software. It even has a Replace functionality that you probably could have used in lieu of stripping the tags. Replace á with a, ó with o, ü with u, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possbilble that Banshee fetched the data from it's database (like most music players do), because there once was a file with the same name at this location and the database wasn't updated.

Please consider using more up to date media formats that don't make it overly complicated to name tracks. I generally prefer OGG with Vorbis (and Sansa Clips seem to support this format), but MP4 with AAC is considered to be the standard in compatibility these days for all devices that don't run open source software.